# setInterval function with focus function in jquery

Tags: jquery

sorry for my question, I don't know what exactly to ask, but what I what to do is to stop setInterval() on focusing textarea. here's my code

```
var timer = null,
    interval = 2000,
    value = 0;

function latest(){
    var mydata = "me="+uid.val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'getlatest.php',
        data: mydata,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){


            $('#append').empty();

            $('#append').append(data);

             $('textarea').focus(function(){
               alert(1);
           }); 

        }

    });

}

 function start(){
    if(timer !== null) return;
    timer = setInterval(latest, interval);
}

function stop(){
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = null;
}
```

What I want to do is to stop the interval when i put the cursor in the textarea. 
Thank you

Comment: Can't you just put stop as the focus function? Like `$('textarea').focus(stop)`?

Comment: Now does the interval has to restart somehow? Would it be your next question? :)  Beware, your code will bind as many as focus event that you make success ajax calls

Comment: Why are you putting `focus` in `success`? Just add `focus` in `ready` function and I think it will work.

Comment: @Akshay I think i get it, OP is adding textarea from ajax call

Comment: If your textarea are dynamics, delegate focus event, e.g: `$('#append').on('focus', 'textarea', stop);`  Set it on document ready handler. Still e.g: `$(function(){$('#append').on('focus', 'textarea', stop);});`

Answer (score 1):

Just bind to onfocus event and pass `stop` function as event handler:

```
$('textarea').focus(stop);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for textarea focus in setInterval and clearInterval in that

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
     if($(textarea).is(":focus") == true){
           clearInterval(interval);
     }
},1000);
```